# websocket stream debounceTime not working in flutter

Tags: flutter, stream-builder

Hi I need to add some delay on my [IOWebSocketChannel](https://pub.dev/documentation/web_socket_channel/latest/io/IOWebSocketChannel-class.html) streem to slow it down.
I used stream.debounceTime(Duration(seconds: 4)) to call the builder method every 4 seconds, but the builder method  never runs. If I remove debounceTime, StreamBuilder works properly.
Please help me what is wrong with debounceTime and where it should be?

```
 class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  IOWebSocketChannel? channel;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    channel?.sink.close();
    channel = IOWebSocketChannel.connect(
      Uri.parse(ApiEndPoint.socketApi),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: false,
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('price'),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          StreamBuilder(
            // use debounceTime to run builder method every 4 seconds
            stream: channel!.stream.debounceTime(Duration(seconds: 4)),
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              print(snapshot);
              return createMyList(snapshot.data);
            },
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: this is not a job for `debounceTime` - see [this](https://medium.com/fantageek/throttle-vs-debounce-in-rxswift-86f8b303d5d4) for more info about debounce

Comment: Thank you, I used `throttleTime` and it seems to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used `throttleTime` instead of `debounceTime`

```
class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  IOWebSocketChannel? channel;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    channel?.sink.close();
    channel = IOWebSocketChannel.connect(
      Uri.parse(ApiEndPoint.socketApi),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: false,
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('price'),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          StreamBuilder(
            // use debounceTime to run builder method every 4 seconds
            stream: channel!.stream.throttleTime (Duration(seconds: 4)),
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              print(snapshot);
              return createMyList(snapshot.data);
            },
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```